# iAds appear and disappear

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, iad

This may just be because im running it in developmental mode on my device but I added ads into my application and they all seem to be working as i would expect, but it seems that after 2-5 minutes it calls the didFailToReceiveAdWithError delegate method and hides the ad. It does come back usually under a minute but it does this often

I was just wondering if this should be something i should be worrying about or if its just related to the developmental debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a non-App Store app or in a beta release of iOS, iAd always uses the test ad.

I would assume that failing to receive an ad occasionally is an unavailability in Apple’s servers. I wonder if they are failing to deliver ads intermittently on purpose in order to help debug when ads really are unavailable.

Comment: I wouldn’t worry about it. If you continue to see this in production, then I would worry.